# How to run a remote bat file on a local computer

Tags: windows-8.1, batch, curl

I need to run a batch file, that is stored on a server, locally on a windows 8.1 machine. I can run a shell script in OS X with a curl:

cURL "file path" | sh

is it possible to cURL in powershell in windows. What would go after the pipe what would interpret the .bat file?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell has the [`Invoke-Expression`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849893.aspx) cmdlet.  You can download a powershell script and run it using:

```
Invoke-Expression ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://example.com/your_script.ps1'))
```

There are severall Powershell utilities that use this to simplify the install project ([See Chocolatey](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Installation#powershell))